# How to animate circular progress bar in a custom dialog, but not in an activity?

Tags: android, progress-bar, customdialog

I knew how to do it in an activity, but when it comes to dialog, I have no idea. When an activity ends, a custom dialog pops out and display the percentage that corresponds to the circular progress bar. I want to animate it and at the same time pass data from activity to custom dialog. The following is the codes...

lvl1 code:

```
imagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                    switch (q) {
                        case 0:
                            q = 1;
                            break;

                        case 1: {                            
                            q = 2;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 2: //same repeated thing, until the end...
case 6 :{//some code}
}
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences
                        (lvl1.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();                   
                editor.putInt("score",s);
                editor.apply();
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(lvl1.this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.test_result);
                        dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                        dialog.setCancelable(true);
                        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                        RelativeLayout wholeScreen = dialog.findViewById(R.id.result);
                        wholeScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                }, 1000);
q=6;
break;
}}}
```

test_result code:

```
public class test_result extends lvl1{
int s;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_result);
    ProgressBar mProgress = findViewById(R.id.circularProgressbar);
    TextView score = findViewById(R.id.score);

    Resources res = getResources();
    Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.circular);
    mProgress.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
    animateScore(0, s, score);
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mProgress, "progress", 0, s);
    animation.setDuration(1500);
    animation.start();

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    s = preferences.getInt("money",0);
}

public void animateScore(int initialValue, int finalValue, final TextView score) {

    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialValue, finalValue);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(1500);

    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            score.setText(String.format("%s%%", valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString()));
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();
}
```

Finally, I cant animate the progress bar, as I just can see the progress bar without any animation. Any helps?

Comment: I think that "extends lvl1" causess the error. How to fix that if that is the case?

Comment: You may be reading the wrong value from your preferences?

Comment: Flo We    Oh yeah, I changed "money" to "score", thus reading the correct preference. However, it still doesn't work and the progress bar is not animated at all. Do you have any solution for animating circular progress bar in custom alert dialog? I know how to animate progress bar in an activity, but in a alert dialog, how to do that?